# Bootstrap links black boxes on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

All of a sudden it seems my links now turn to black boxes while being hovered on as well as turn grey after being clicked on. I don't remember changing anything that might have caused this. Instead of posting my 1300 lines of css does anyone have an idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inspect the element's hover state. If you use Google Chrome, open up inspector, right click the element, 'Force Element State' > :hover. You should be able to identify the problem using your inspector and checking the CSS styles for that element.

Comment: Thanks, solved it. If you're familiar with rails i made a new scaffold and forgot about the css it auto generates.

Comment: Just thought I'd note for future cases I found this via Google and the answer in my case was in this comment from @user2759575 instead. If you're using Bootstrap SASS gem with Rails and use rails generate to create anything it will make a scaffolds.scss in app/assets/stylesheets that you need to change or remove. This fixes the odd behavior you'll see in your app where the Rails defaults and Bootstrap are in disagreement.